# Image takes all available height and kicks out sibling elements out of parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I try to place some images using grid element. Each grid element consists of one images, and 2 simple text elements. Problem is, the image in each grid item element kicks out the 2 text elements out of the grid item itself.

How could I fix it?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="shuffleContainer">
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--1">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--2">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--3">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--4">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--5">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--6">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
        <div class="postContainer postContainer--7">
            <img class="postContainer__image" src="./images/post1.jpg" alt="post">
            <span class="postContainer__title">Bla bla bla nice post</span>
            <span class="postContainer__description">Description post</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the SCSS code:

```
@import "./config";

.shuffleContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 250px);
    grid-gap: 15px;
    background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
    padding: 20px;

    .postContainer {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 5px;

        &--1 {
            grid-row: 1 / span 1;
            grid-column: 1 / span 1;
        }

        &--2 {
            grid-row: 1 / span 1;
            grid-column: 2 / span 1;
        }

        &--3 {
            grid-row: 1 / span 1;
            grid-column: 3 / span 1;
        }

        &--4 {
            grid-row: 1 / span 2;
            grid-column: 4 / span 1;
        }

        &--5 {
            grid-row: 2 / span 2;
            grid-column: 1 / span 2;
        }

        &--6 {
            grid-row: 2 / span 1;
            grid-column: 3 / span 1;
        }

        &--7 {
            grid-row: 3 / span 1;
            grid-column: 3 / span 2;
        }

        &__image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        &__title {
            color: #355087;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-size: 1.6rem;
        }

        &__description {
            font-size: 1.4rem;
        }
    }
}
```

`config.scss` file isn't that relevant for this code. Could be omitted.

[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6ku7.jpg)

Comment: Please using a snippet if you use a `SCSS` for question

Comment: Dude, nobody's gonna read all that code. Please, provide only the snippet where the issue is.

Comment: @Deadpool added

Comment: @Adhitya added.